# Aggregation with ORDER BY in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I found an interesting behavior in Oracle and MySQL databases. I'll follow with Oracle examples.

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(a int, b int);

INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, 1);

SELECT SUM(a)
FROM t
ORDER BY b;
```

I expected the query to fail with `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`, but it succeeded and returned `6`. There's technically no `GROUP BY` expression in the query, but there is an aggregation, therefore an empty `GROUP BY ()` is assumed. You can even add this clause to the query, the result is the same. This query fails in PostgreSQL, but MySQL also supports it. I wonder what is the semantics of `ORDER BY` in this case.

I thought that perhaps the sorting is applied before the aggregation, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

[image]

The correct way to order the data before the aggregation is to use the `WITHIN GROUP` clause.

[image]

Then I thought that maybe the statement is equivalent to a subquery with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(a)
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM t
  ORDER BY b
)
```

In the above query, the `ORDER BY` clause is also ignored, but this is legal in SQL. So my guess was that maybe in case the `ORDER BY` clause cannot be evaluated after grouping, Oracle evaluates it before grouping. But this query refutes that idea:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(a)
FROM t
ORDER BY LISTAGG(a), b
```

In this query, the `ORDER BY` clause can be evaluated neither before, nor after grouping. Before grouping, there's no `listagg(a)`, after grouping, there's no `b`. But the query still succeeds. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I also looked at the EXPLAIN PLAN output. For the original query, it shows exactly the same plan with and without ORDER BY clause, the ORDER BY clause is ignored.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    26 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     3 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another interesting point is that as soon as there is a non-empty GROUP BY clause, the query fails, if you try to sort by an expression that cannot be evaluated after grouping. My impression is that this behavior is an oversight in Oracle, that it should have never been supported, but they're keeping it for backwards compatibility.

Is this a known issue, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sub-queries are just in-line-views. They're sets just like any other set. Also, SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative language. This means that you declare an expression but the engine determines how to solve it. And not necessarily in the "order" you wrote it. Well, in SQL sets are explicitly considered un-ordered. Even if you order a set in its definition, when used in another scope or context it's considered unordered. This all means that a set's ORDER BY does not *dictate* the order it is processed or Aggregated. It *may* do, but that's coincidence and not a guarantee.

Comment: oracle is not mysql

Comment: I'm surprised the `order by listagg(a), b` doesn't throw an error. But, as you're aggregating to a single row, it's possible the optimiser realises the ordering has no effect (no matter how you order one row, that row never changes position), and in realising that it never checks the order by, and so never encounters an issue. I'd consider that a bug, but one of Minimal consequence.

Comment: and as this is lcearly oracle, did you check the manual about LIstagg you have a in built order by why not use it https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: I would be careful mixing mysql with oracle and then with postgresql. They each have different syntax and semantics, and very different parsers and optimisers. You very much *can* [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in postgresql, for example.

Comment: @nbk the op does use the `within group` clause at one point. This isn't a "how to do x" question, it's a "why does behaviour x happen" question, based on misconceptions about sql (primarily not recognising how a declarative language works, or that sets are always considered unordered when consumed).

Comment: @MatBailie as all result sets are unordered/unsorted by nature as are all tables for that matter, the behaviour is by design and needs no further explanation

Comment: @nbk The op clearly doesn't know about that design feature, and so articulating that feature IS the answer. "needs no further explanation" is unhelpful to everyone. I've always taught my teams that there are NO stupid questions, and that asking fundamental questions is a Good thing.

Comment: It's unclear (to me anyway) if you're asking for a general explanation about how ordering is applied in various scenarios, or specifically why you don't get ORA-00979 in your first query - which seems to be a minor bug relating to order-by elimination, as MatBailie said.

Comment: FYI this query pattern works in ORACLE 21c:
SELECT column_1, LISTAGG(column_2,'-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_2)
FROM data
GROUP BY column_1
ORDER BY LISTAGG(column_2) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_2)
;
without syntax error and gives the correct results.

Comment: @p3consulting I'm unclear how that bears any relation to anything in the OP or the comments. I could also state that 1+1=2...

Comment: @MatBailie: you stated here above "as you're aggregating to a single row, it's possible the optimiser realises the ordering has no effect" : the test I did just shows  that this continues to work even with several rows returned, with or without WITHIN clause, at least in 21c.

Comment: @p3consulting The `[WITHIN GROUP] (order_by_clause)`  was mandatory in [Oracle 18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) or below and is not mandatory from [Oracle 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html). Regardless, the `WITHIN` clause is irrelevant to the OP's question as they are not asking about ordering within the aggregation function but are asking about ordering the result set.

Comment: @MTO testing with and without WITHIN GROUP was just to get more info about a possible bug's context.

Comment: @MatBailie I don't agree it's a misconception about declarative languages. If an invalid column in ORDER BY can be ignored, if the result is not at least 2 rows, then consider query: `SELECT a FROM (SELECT a, non_existent_col FROM t)`: can/should the engine ignore `non_existent_col`, because it's projected out? It think it must not.

Comment: @oliv The declarative language aspect of my comments is related to why the ordering is not guaranteed in `SELECT x FROM (SELECT x FROM foo ORDER BY y) AS bar`; because sets in SQL are considered unordered and so the execution plan doesn't NEED to implement the sort. In an imperative language it WOULD implement the sort.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT SUM(a)
FROM t
ORDER BY b;
```

Means `SUM` the values in the `a` column across the entire result set.

Then considering the `ORDER BY` clause, the [Oracle documentation for a `SELECT` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) states:

> #### `order_by_clause`
>
> Use the `ORDER BY` clause to order rows returned by the statement. Without an `order_by_clause`, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Restrictions on the `ORDER BY` Clause
>
> The following restrictions apply to the `ORDER BY` clause:
>
> - If you have specified the `DISTINCT` operator in this statement, then this clause cannot refer to columns unless they appear in the select list.
> - An `order_by_clause` can contain no more than 255 expressions.
> - You cannot order by a `LOB`, `LONG`, or `LONG RAW` column, nested table, or varray.
> - If you specify a `group_by_clause` in the same statement, then this `order_by_clause` is restricted to the following expressions:
>
>   - Constants
>   - Aggregate functions
>   - Analytic functions
>   - The functions `USER`, `UID`, and `SYSDATE`
>   - Expressions identical to those in the `group_by_clause`
>   - Expressions comprising the preceding expressions that evaluate to the same value for all rows in a group

Which for your query:

- you do not use `DISTINCT`;
- there are fewer than 255 expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause;
- you do not use `LOB`, `LONG`, or `LONG RAW` columns or nested tables or varrays; and
- there is no `GROUP BY` clause in your statement.

Therefore, by Oracle's documentation, there are no applicable restrictions on the columns of the `ORDER BY` clause. However, the `ORDER BY` clause is effectively irrelevant as, due to the aggregation, there will only be one row in the result set.

---

> Another interesting point is that as soon as there is a non-empty GROUP BY clause, the query fails

In that case, the restrictions on the `GROUP BY` clause will apply and the valid values in the `ORDER BY` clause are limited to (as stated in the quoted documentation):

> - Constants
> - Aggregate functions
> - Analytic functions
> - The functions `USER`, `UID`, and `SYSDATE`
> - Expressions identical to those in the `group_by_clause`
> - Expressions comprising the preceding expressions that evaluate to the same value for all rows in a group

The `b` column does not match any of those restrictions so, yes, the query will fail.

Comment: After studying the issue and reading the comments to the question, I think it's a minor bug. But thanks for the docs excerpts.

Comment: @oliv You could argue about whether the specification is correct, but if an implementation conforms to the specification (which MT0 has demonstrated to be the case), how do you propose to argue that it's a bug? It is quite literally behaving as intended.